# UISegmentControl as NavigationController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to make some custom views and I'm wondering how can I go about implementing something like this where you have a UISegmentControl (or something alike) and you switch between different view controllers but the segment control remains in the same spot (don't mind the different size of the pictures). Like a navigation controller but with a segment instead of it. Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks

[image] [image]

Comment: I have provided you the answer . But if you are still confused,then tell me... i will provide you more Simplified answer.

Comment: Hey,have you solved your problem??? if yes,then do upvote my answer and accept my answer, or if No,then please tell your doubt.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done easily. You just need to use navigation controller but **hide the navigation bar on all views**. And then you can use

`[self.navigationController pushViewController:@"Your viewController to which you want to navigate" animated:YES];`

on select segment index. and for going back from any of those view controller,you just need to implement this

`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` on selected segment index's button action. I hope this is going to help you. Happy coding..!!!

Comment: If I make UISegmentControl a child of the navigation bar and hide it then the navigation bar and the segment control will both be hidden :)

Comment: make the color of navigation bar transparent and disable navigation bar.... i hope your purpose will be achieved.

Comment: your solution implies making the UISegmentControl a child of the UINavigationController and then change the alpha of the navigation controller to 0.0 witch will also make the segment transparent. I have tried. It doesn't work

Comment: Am not telling you to make segment conrol transparent... do make transparent navigation bar only..and try to put segment control just below the navigation bar,so that it wouldn't get affected by navigation bar's transparency..

Comment: ok but once I do push the next view controller's view won't have the segment controller since it's only in one view controller.

Comment: yes... i got it. Actually you have to show segment control on each view.set any flag on selected segment index's value and show segment control on each view(applying that flag value on segment control so that it will show selected segment only).

Answer (score 0):

You can create ViewController with segment control and array, which will contain other controllers.
On segment change you should take view from one of the controllers from array and add it like subview to parent ViewControllerView.
This will look something like this

```
//in ViewControllerView.m
-(void)touchUpInsideSegmentIndex:(NSUInteger)segmentIndex {
   //delegate is your ViewController
    UIView * newToolView = [delegate viewAtIndex:segmentIndex];
    //contentView declared in ViewControllerView.h
    if (newToolView != contentView && newToolView) {
        [contentView removeFromSuperview];
        [contentView release];
        contentView = [newToolView retain];
        [self addSubview:contentView];
        [self setNeedsLayout];
    }
}

//in ViewController.m
- (UIView*)viewAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    //yourControllersArray is an array of your controllers
    if (index < 0 || index >= [yourControllersArray count]) {       
        NSLog(@"View At Wrong Index %d (max=%d)", index, [yourControllersArray count]);
        return nil;
    }
    return [[yourControllersArray objectAtIndex: index] view];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Position UISegmentedControl in navigation bar.
2. Set navigation bar transparent.
3. In UISegmentedControl method push and pop view controllers from UINavigationController stack, or show and dismiss modal